# How can I show or hide a button if all CheckBoxList Items are checked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i have this code  .I want to make this like , when i checked all items , a button shows up .

```
        string connStr = "myconnstring" ;
        SqlCommand com;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        string s1 = string.Empty;
        foreach (ListItem item in this.CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                s1 = item.ToString();
                com = new SqlCommand("Insert into tblml values('" + s1 + "')", con);
                con.Open();
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        Response.Write("Inserted Successfully");
```

Any help appriciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could determine if they are all checked like this:

```
var isAllChecked = this.CheckBoxList1.Items.OfType<ListItem>().All(l => l.Selected);
```

and then you could hide/show your button using that variable:

```
this.button.Visible = isAllChecked;
```

---

Another option would be to create a variable at the top of the loop you already have:

```
var isAllChecked = true;
```

and then inside the loop add an `else` to the `if (item.Selected)`:

```
    ...
}
else { isAllChecked = false; }
```

Comment: But i cant use  CheckBoxList1.OfType<ListItem>() this part .I have Linq in my namespace but asking me IENumarable or ParallelLinq

Comment: @Abdullah, please see my edit, I missed the `.Items` accessor.